# Macbook Pro (2021) with Apple Care and multiple repair reasons. How does the repair work?

Tags: keyboard, battery, applecare

I have a Macbook Pro 16" from 2021 with Apple Care Plus.
A few weeks ago, (sticky) liquid spilled over the keyboard. All keys still work, but some get stuck when typing.
The battery only has 83% of the design capacity left.
Now I can claim Apple Care Plus in the event of liquid damage and apply for a repair with an additional payment of €259.
My questions about this:

- Would the complete lower part of the Macbook be replaced or actually just the keyboard?
- Will the battery also be replaced during the repair and will it be back to 100% afterwards?
- The SSD is fixed on the logic board. Will the Mabook be set to factory settings after the repair and will I have to restore a backup?
- Has anyone here had similar experiences - how is the repair process going?

Comment: Have you called Apple and asked? They'll probably have the most complete info.

Comment: Yes, I will do that of course. I just want to check other users experience as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can certainly tell you that you will have to restore your backup when it is returned to you. When you start up your Mac, it will ask you if you want to transfer data from a backup disk.

They will only replace the battery if that has been agreed. Normally, they will only repair batteries that have fallen below 80%. When you take it in, they should assess the condition of the battery with analysis software, and make a decision.

Again, whether they replace the keyboard, or just clean it, will be up to them: but presumably they will do whatever needs doing to repair the damage.